# "Unresolved text symbol" -- how do I find the right library

Tags: c, compilation, x11

Please pardon the newbie question, my C is very, very rusty.
Trying to build xrunclient from http://www.leftfield.org/~dd/sw.html, on IRIX64, I'm confronted with:

*ld32: ERROR: 33 : Unresolved text symbol "XOpenDisplay"*

I figure this is because it can't find the proper library, but it finds the header files without complaint. How can I identify which library has that routine defined so I can make sure it's in the library path?

Answer (score 3):

Teach a man to fish:

```
nm -o /usr/lib/lib*.a 2>/dev/null | 
grep  XOpenDisplay | 
grep -w T
```

What this does is

1. Ask for the symbols in all of the libraries in `/usr/lib`.  (On a 64-bit system you may need to check `/usr/lib64`.)  The `-o` option prints not only the symbol but also the name of the file it comes from.
2. Grab the symbol you care about: `XOpenDisplay`.
3. Grep for *definitions* of that symbol in the *text* section—the lone `T` is how `nm(1)` signals a definition in the text section.  I might have also tried `grep -w [TD]` to get text or data.

The answer is a little surprising:

```
/usr/lib/libSDL.a:SDL_x11dyn.o:00000380 T XOpenDisplay
/usr/lib/libX11.a:OpenDis.o:00000420 T XOpenDisplay
```

I'm not sure what `-lSDL` is (if I cared I would google for it), but there's `-lX11` as large as life.

Now you can find any missing symbol you want :-)

Comment: http://libsdl.org/ Looks like it contains a bunch of stubs for the Xlib functions so that it can load without libX11 and still operate, but can also load with libX11 and forward calls to it.

Comment: You'll note that there's a `U XOpenDisplay` entry in `libSDL.a:SDL_x11video.o`.  I'm kinda surprised that this funny setup works, but apparently...!

Comment: nm - that was the utility I was trying to remember

Answer (score 1):

The answer is libX11.so -- it contains the basic Xlib routines, and you can tell this is an Xlib routine because it starts with a plain "X". If it started with "Xt", then you'd know it's a method in the Xt widget set.

I don't believe that the name of this library has changed in 15+ years, so the compile command shown in the book should work for you. I believe that the library name is also listed in the manpage for the X routines (which of course means that you have to have manpages available, and not everyone does).

Other than that, grep may be your best bet, although grepping across /usr/lib is going to turn up both references to the function and the declaration, so that probably isn't useful. There's also a command-line utility (you are running on Linux, right?) that will show the contents of a .so, which may be useful as well.

Edit: ah, Irix, not Linux; didn't notice that on first read. I think the best approach is going to be finding the manpages.

Comment: AFAIK, the X11 libraries on IRIX are actually nicely integrated in `/usr/lib` instead of odd locations like `/usr/openwin/lib` or `/usr/X11R6/lib`, so if the X11 development kit was installed, the linker *should* have picked up the libraries... dunno, it's a mystery to me, too.

Answer (score 0):

X11 years later, I can reveal the answer to this question *specifically* pertaining to IRIX.

```
CC mycode.cpp -lX11
```

Who would have thought that somebody would still be looking for this information in 2020 :)